# Loading session needed external website, other than by iFrame

Tags: session, iframe

I wrote a reservation script that needs users to be logged in first. Works fine. Now I want to embed this scrip on another website, that is running on another server via an iFrame. The problem oembeddccuring is that logged in users lose their session when they are redirected to another page. I found out that this is caused by modern browsers, and has something  to do with security. If you have an session id on one page, and are redirected to another page, you will lose your session id. I found several fixes for this, but all those fixes are not working anymore.

I tried embed and also object calling this external URL, but it is still losing the session. Then I was thinking to rebuild my script, so it is running like an API. The external server loads a JavaScript, and in that JavaScript, ajax is calling all that is necessary.
When a user is logged in, the ajax response send back to the external server contains the session ID. Every time, a paged is requested, this ID should be send along via ajax.Reservetions script picks this up, and treats it like session ID.

My concern, is this going to work or should I use another technique?